# How to call child component method from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

In my Reactjs app, I need to have a parent component (a wizard) named **Wizard.js** and a number of child components (steps of the wizard) named **PrimaryForm.js**, SecondaryForm.js etc. They all are Class based components with some local validation functions.

**Previous and Next buttons** to advance the steps, reside in the Wizard.js.

To advance the next step of the wizard, I'm trying to call a method from PrimaryForm. I checked similar questions in Stackoverflow; tried using ref or forwardRef, but I could not make it work. I currently receive "**TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleCheckServer' of null**" error.

Below are my parent and child classes. Any help about what I would be doing wrong is appreciated.

**Wizard.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
...

const getSteps = () => {
  return [
    'Info',
    'Source Details',
    'Target Details',
    'Configuration'
  ];
}

class Wizard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.firstRef = React.createRef();
    this.handleNext = this.handleNext.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      activeStep: 1,
    }
}

  componentDidMount() {}

  handleNext = () =>  {
    if (this.state.activeStep === 1) {
      this.firstRef.current.handleCheckServer(); <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< This is where I try to call child method
    }
    this.setState(state => ({
      activeStep: state.activeStep + 1,
    }));
  };

  handleBack = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      activeStep: state.activeStep - 1,
    }));
  };

  handleReset = () => {
    this.setState({
      activeStep: 0,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const steps = getSteps();
    const currentPath = this.props.location.pathname;
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Topbar currentPath={currentPath} />
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <Grid container spacing={2} justify="center" direction="row">
            <Grid container spacing={2} className={classes.grid} justify="center" direction="row">
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <div className={classes.topBar}>
                  <div className={classes.block}>
                    <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>Wizard</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body1">Follow the wizard steps to create a configuration.</Typography>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid container spacing={2} alignItems="center" justify="center" className={classes.grid}>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <div className={classes.stepContainer}>
                  <div className={classes.bigContainer}>
                    <Stepper classes={{ root: classes.stepper }} activeStep={this.state.activeStep} alternativeLabel>
                      {steps.map(label => {
                        return (
                          <Step key={label}>
                            <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
                          </Step>
                        );
                      })}
                    </Stepper>
                  </div>
                  <PrimaryForm ref={this.firstRef} />
                </div>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid container spacing={2} className={classes.grid}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <div className={classes.flexBar}>
                <Tooltip title="Back to previous step">
                  <div>
                    <Button variant="contained"
                      disabled={(this.state.activeStep === 0)}
                      className={classes.actionButton}
                      onClick={this.handleBack}
                      size='large'>
                      <BackIcon className={classes.rightIcon} />Back
                      </Button>
                  </div>
                </Tooltip>
                <Tooltip title="Proceed the next step">
                  <div>
                    <Button
                      variant="contained" className={classes.actionButton}
                      color="primary"
                      size='large'
                      disabled={!(!this.state.isFormValid || this.state.isTestWaiting)}
                      onClick={this.handleNext}>
                    <ForwardIcon className={this.props.classes.rightIcon}/>Next</Button>
                  </div>
                </Tooltip>

                <Tooltip title="Cancel creating new configuration">
                  <Button variant="contained" color="default" className={classes.actionButton}
                    component={Link} to={'/configs'} style={{ marginLeft: 'auto' }}>
                    <CancelIcon className={classes.rightIcon} />Cancel
                      </Button>
                </Tooltip>
              </div>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
export default withRouter(withStyles(styles)(Wizard));
```

**PrimaryForm.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
...

class PrimaryForm extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleCheckServer = this.handleCheckServer.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      hostname: {
        value: "localhost",
        isError: false,
        errorText: "",
      },
      serverIp: {
        value: "127.0.0.1",
        isError: false,
        errorText: "",
      },
      isFormValid: true,
      isTestValid: true,
      testErrorMessage: "",
      isTestWaiting: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() { }

  handleCheckServer() {
    alert('Alert from Child. Server check will be done here');
  }

  evaluateFormValid = (prevState) => {
    return ((prevState.hostname.value !== "" && !prevState.hostname.isError) &&
      (prevState.serverIp.value !== "" && !prevState.serverIp.isError));
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    var valResult;
    switch (event.target.id) {
      case 'hostname':
        valResult = PrimaryFormValidator.validateHostname(event.target.value, event.target.labels[0].textContent);
        this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          hostname:
          {
            value: event.target.value,
            isError: valResult.isError,
            errorText: valResult.errorText,
          },
        });
        break;
      case 'serverIp':
        valResult = PrimaryFormValidator.validateIpAddress(event.target.value, event.target.labels[0].textContent);
        this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          serverIp:
          {
            value: event.target.value,
            isError: valResult.isError,
            errorText: valResult.errorText,
          }
        });
        break;
      default:
    }
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      isFormValid: this.evaluateFormValid(prevState),
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className={classes.bigContainer}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            <div>
              <div>
                <Typography variant="subtitle1" gutterBottom className={classes.subtitle1} color='secondary'>
                  Primary System
              </Typography>
                <Typography variant="body1" gutterBottom>
                  Information related with the primary system.
              </Typography>
              </div>
              <div className={classes.bigContainer}>
                <form className={classes.formArea}>
                  <TextField className={classes.formControl}
                    id="hostname"
                    label="FQDN Hostname *"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    value={this.state.hostname.value}
                    error={this.state.hostname.isError}
                    helperText={this.state.hostname.errorText}
                    variant="outlined" autoComplete="off" />
                  <TextField className={classes.formControl}
                    id="serverIp"
                    label="Server Ip Address *"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    value={this.state.serverIp.value}
                    error={this.state.serverIp.isError}
                    helperText={this.state.serverIp.errorText}
                    variant="outlined" autoComplete="off" />
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Paper>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
export default withRouter(withStyles(styles)(PrimaryForm));
```

(ps: I would like to solve this without another framework like Redux, etc if possible)

Comment: can you provide a minimal working example on stackblitz? ref totally works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-f98wtv

Comment: @MarkusDresch, weird enough, I was able to make it work in stackblitz: (https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ywxbdi ) but it does not work in my local VS Code environment. The code is not the exact same, as stackblitz version is a prototype; but I compared relevant section of code and they are %100 same. Very weird...

Comment: another thing I should note is, when I use **ref={...}**, it gives a warning in VS Code Debug mode as follows: "Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?" .................... and when I use **forwardRef={..}** in stackblitz, I get error of "Cannot read property 'handleTestConnection' of null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example in Typescript.
The idea is that the parent passes its callback to the child. The child calls the parent's callback supplying its own e.g. child callback as the argument. The parent stores what it got (child callback) in a class member variable and calls it later.

```js
import * as React from 'react'

interface ICallback {
  (num: number): string
}

type ChildProps = {
  parent_callback: (f: ICallback) => void;
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props: ChildProps) {
    super(props);
    props.parent_callback(this.childCallback);
  }

  childCallback: ICallback = (num: number) => {
    if (num == 5) return "hello";
    return "bye";
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div>Child</div>
      </>
    )
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  readonly state = { msg: "<not yet set>" };

  letChildRegisterItsCallback = (fun: ICallback) => {
    this.m_ChildCallback = fun;
  }

  callChildCallback() {
    const str = this.m_ChildCallback? this.m_ChildCallback(5) : "<callback not set>";
    console.log("Child callback returned string: " + str);
    return str;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState((prevState) => { return {...prevState, msg: this.callChildCallback()} });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Child {...{ parent_callback: this.letChildRegisterItsCallback }} />
        <div>{this.state.msg}</div>
      </>
    )
  }

  m_ChildCallback: ICallback | undefined = undefined;
}
```

P.S.
The same code in Javascript. The only difference is that `interface, type, readonly` and type annotations are taken out. Pasting into [here](https://babeljs.io/repl/) confirms it's a valid ES2015 stage-2 code.

```js
class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    props.parent_callback(this.childCallback);
  }

  childCallback = (num) => {
    if (num == 5) return "hello";
    return "bye";
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div>Child</div>
      </>
    )
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = { msg: "<not yet set>" };

  letChildRegisterItsCallback = (fun) => {
    this.m_ChildCallback = fun;
  }

  callChildCallback() {
    const str = this.m_ChildCallback? this.m_ChildCallback(5) : "<callback not set>";
    console.log("Child callback returned string: " + str);
    return str;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState((prevState) => { return {...prevState, msg: this.callChildCallback()} });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Child {...{ parent_callback: this.letChildRegisterItsCallback }} />
        <div>{this.state.msg}</div>
      </>
    )
  }

  m_ChildCallback = undefined;
}
```

Comment: Hi, this seems to be a nice alternative but we do not want to use TypeScript. I need to get over this need in Javascript.

Comment: Hi, The idea to use callbacks applies equally to Typescript and Javascript. I added the latter.

Comment: This works like a charm. You saved my day bro! Granted the correct answer.